# Saving the information in database and then Post request to external API using .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to .NET CORE and I'm trying to work with external API's using .NET CORE application MVC architecture. As a newbie it is really difficult for me to grasp the root cause of MVC, well having said that I did my own research and have understand a lot of things. Right now I have two Questions (1st one is about suggesting How to start, 2nd one is about the work I have done till now)

**Question 1 (Suggestion)**
So as I said I'm trying to work on calling external API's using MVC architecture. What I want to do is lets suppose the admin is logging in first time, the first username and password is default "admin" and "myadminpassword" respectively. To login admin have to provide with a new password which is send as a request body to the API. Now I want that new password to save to my db and then from there to the API endpoint. Is it doable? and Is it a good idea?

**Question 2 (Approach Till Now)**

So getting help from a lots of tutorial below is my code what I have done till now.

**Main_Application / Areas / Application / View / Home / Index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "WhAuth", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label>
        Username:
        <input type="text" placeholder="admin" readonly />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
        Password:
        <input type="text" placeholder="*****" readonly />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
        Enter New Password:
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.New_password, 5,5,new { })
    </label>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Sign up as Admin</button>
}
```

**Main_Application / Areas / Application / Models / AdminLoginModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PTCConnector.Areas.Whatsapp.Models
{
    public class AdminLoginModel
    {
        public string Df_username = "admin";
        public string Df_password = "anySecretPassword";
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "New Password Is Required")]
        public string New_password { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Main_Application / Models / DB / whapp.cs**

```
public class whapp : BaseEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string New_Password { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string WhatsappId { get; set; } //Whatsapp ID
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string recipient_type { get; set; }
    public string Messagebody { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Group_id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Media_Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

**Main_Application / Data / ApplicationDBContext.cs**

```
public DbSet<whapp> whapp { get; set; }
```

**Main_Application / Areas / Application / Controllers / WhAuthController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PTCConnector.Areas.Whatsapp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PTCConnector.Areas.Whatsapp.Controllers
{
    [Area("Whatsapp")]
    [TypeFilter(typeof(AdminActionFilter))]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class WhAuthController : Controller
    {
        public AdminLoginModel whLogin = new AdminLoginModel();

        public async Task Login()
        {
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
            };
            var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{whLogin.Df_username}:{whLogin.Df_password}");

            var Base64Credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Base64Credentials);

            // Set Base64Credentials as Authorization header with Prefix 
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Base64Credentials);

            // Just some data for POST, change freely!
            var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "new_password", $"{whLogin.New_password}" } //
            };
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.Values);
            Console.WriteLine("here 1");
            // Encode the data in FORM URL Data
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);



            // Make Async Post Call with Client. Parameters are URL and Data to POST!
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:9090/v1/users/login", content);

            // Async!! - Read the response content as String
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Print out the Response String for Debugging!
            //Console.WriteLine(responseString);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Check");
            Console.WriteLine("CheckNow");
        }
    }
}
```

**Main_Application / Startup.cs**

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext> ... //

            services.AddHttpClient("WhappClient", client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:9090/v1/users/login");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("username", "admin");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("password", "anySecretPassword");
            });
```

Everything is working fine, my main aim is to post the data into the database also, so the information could be saved, also the return result from the API's also have to be saved in a database for future use.

**Edit**
The application is running on docker container the path of which is `https://localhost:9090/`
My aim is that when the user fill the information of new_password in the input field and press submit, the application should hit the controller with the new_password like below.

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "new_password", $"{whLogin.New_password}" } //
            };
```

which is then hit to the specific endpoint as mentioned 
`await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:9090/v1/users/login", content);`
the return will be a token that I want to save in the database for future endpoint calls, moreover then the given new_password also be saved in the hash format in my database.

Comment: What's the problem after all? Are you trying to save data to database and getting an error? You should register the DbContext with Dependency Injection and define the database connection string under `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: @iamdlm I want to fill a form by admin/user and when the user put a new password and submit it I want the new_password to be saved in my database and at the same time return a response which will be a token in this case, then I want to save that token into my database to use it for other endpoints

Comment: The question is where are you falling down? What have you tried? What's not working? Your question is too broad. Make an attempt at a solution, if you haven't already, and then update your question with *specific* problem(s) you run into. If you get any exceptions, post those along with the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Starting an answer since I can't simply comment yet. Can you provide some more information and context as to what you are trying to accomplish here? What is the external API's purpose, as it appears to be another local project? Is the project we are looking at an MVC project or a Web API project? Is the user store local or are you using an external identity provider?

So far you've taken in some input data, encoded it as a Base64 string and then sent it to your other local API. Where does the database save, that you mentioned, happen? Also, if your storing the password in a database, make sure you take the proper steps to hash and salt it before saving it. Honestly you should just use the built in ASP.NET Identity if you need a user/authentication framework. As someone else commented, where are you getting hung up, what is going wrong?

I hope this doesn't sound interrogating with all the questions lol! I'm just sure we could help some more if we get some more background and details about whats going on. If you can provide some of this info, I can edit my answer to hopefully be of more assistance.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Actually, I am working on an application which is running on docker container and I am trying to hit the end points. As I'm new to .netcore MVC, it took me sometime to understand the basics. You can see my next comment, may be it will be more clear. I will edit the question

Comment: @FarrukhAhmedKhan Not sure if you're still in need of help, but is the question on how to save it to your database ? You said everything is working fine in your question, so just trying to figure out where to help. If you just need to save to the DB, look into Entity Framework Core on Microsofts Docs and you will need to setup a DbContext and then inject it with dependency injection.